# Delphi2010 DBGrid1 rows selection and frxReport1.Print

Tags: delphi, fastreport, dbgrid

I'm a bit confused...
I have a typical procedure where:

```
for nJ := 0 to DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count-1 Do Begin
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.GotoBookmark(pointer(DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Items[nJ]));

*Do some stuff to get data for a report*

frxReport1.LoadFromFile('report.fr3');
frxReport1.PrepareReport();
frxReport1.PrintOptions.Printer := ComboBox1.Text;
frxReport1.Print;

end;
```

Everything is fine untill I have more than one selection (for example 2-3 rows or whole grid).
In debug mode this loop runs once ok (SelectedRows.Count value is for example 3) and after going for another run it sets the Count value to 0 each time thus giving me Access Violation error.
It only happens on frxReport1.Print (same thing with frxReport1.Export(frxPDFExport1)).
If I remove anything related to printing or exporting loop runs fine till the end.

Funny thing is that I have old application in Delphi 2006 which runs fine and now this happened in Delphi 2010. Both are using FR 4.0.

Help sad.gif It drives me crazy.

Comment: If `DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count` returns 0, the loop won't enter. There's something else wrong in your code.

Comment: Well this loop works fine untill I insert frxReport1.Print; To be clear it returns selected rows once (during first run) and after hiting Print and going back it resets count to 0.

Comment: What is the relationship between the grid and the report? What is *Do some stuff to get data for a report*??

Comment: I'm running two queries (master and detail) to fetch data for the report. The grid only gives me the header id's which I assign to query via DBGrid1.SelectedField.DataSet.FieldByName('id').AsString.

Comment: That `SelectedField` access looks very dangerous. Why don't you use `DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet` as before ? I don't have time to test this, but I would expect that if you don't disable controls and jump through the dataset, the grid will lose the previously `SelectedField` and you get AV there. But it's just a wild guess...

Comment: I did DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('id').AsString; No luck. Also Disabling Controls didn't help.

Comment: Oh and please bear in mind that everything works fine in other procedures like running insert/update querries after looping through dataset, generating log files etc. Only when I want to print the report I get the AV and zeroed Count. :(

Comment: Have you tried getting a stack trace of when the AV occurs?

Comment: Yes it occurs directly when frxReport1.Print is called. Without it whole procedure runs smoothly. Funny fact is that in other application I have exact same procedure and it runs smoothly :))

Comment: Well now I see that after first run dataset is being closed...